# Positive roots of polynomial $q(x)=p(x)+k^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Let $p(x)$ a polynomial of degree $n\in\mathbb N$ such that
$$p(x)=0$$
has exactly $n$ real and positive solutions. Is it true that polynomial $q(x)=p(x)+k^2$, for $k\in\mathbb R$ has only positive roots?

I think the answer is: yes. Because the sum of a function to a number only has the effect of translate it upwards and downwards.

Comment: How about $p(x)=-(x-1)(x-2)$ and $k=\sqrt{6}$?

Comment: $q$ could have roots in the complex plane outside the real axis. Do you mean that the real roots of $q$ should be positive?

Comment: If you require $p(x)$ to be monic, then how about $p(x)=(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$ and $k=\sqrt{24}$?

Comment: If you want $p(x)$ to be monic and nonlinear such that $q(x)=p(x)+k^2$ has only real roots, then $p(x)=(x-1)(x-2)(x-8)$ and $k=\sqrt{18}$ is another counterexample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $P(x)=x-1$, which has the root $x=1$.

Now consider $Q(x)=x+3$ ($k=2$), which has the root $x=-3$.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not necessarily true.

Consider the polynomial $$P(x)=(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$$ If we select $k=4$, then the we get $$Q(x)=(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)+16$$which has a negative root and the others are now non-real.